# How to install Lao language on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: language-support

I am trying to install Lao language but I cannot find lao at language support app. How can I install Lao language on ubuntu 2004?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Sorry.

The reason is that no Ubuntu language packs are present for Lao, since too few strings have been translated into Lao.

If you like, you can get in touch with the [Ubuntu Lao translators team](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-l10n-lo) and offer your help to improve the translation coverage.